# What does it mean to open a network interface driver?

Tags: networking, network-programming, drivers, .net-micro-framework, network-interface

To work with GHI network interface drivers, we first need to call `Open()`. What does it mean to open a network interface? [The documentation](https://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/Library_Documentation_v4.2/Premium/html/00835a13-bebf-616b-6c85-0fc821adb955.htm) says nothing other than that the method call is required.

E.g.

```
var wiFiRs9110 = new WiFiRS9110(
    SPI.SPI_module.SPI2,
    GHI.Pins.G120.P1_10,
    GHI.Pins.G120.P2_11,
    GHI.Pins.G120.P1_9, 4000);

wiFiRs9110.Open(); // What does this do?

wiFiRs9110.EnableStaticIP(IpAddress, SubnetMask, GatewayAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine that a piece of hardware would require some initialization before it can be used.

They *could* have chosen to integrate the code from `Open()` in the constructor and `Close()` in the `Dispose()` method, but then:

- All parameters that affect *how* the hardware/driver/class is initialized must then be passed in the constructor (event handlers are a good example here, you don't want to miss the first event)
- You cannot "release" (or `Close()`) the network interface without disposing the object, so if you'd want to access it again you'd have to pass the same parameters to a new instance again
- If anything goes wrong, the constructor would have to throw an exception. It makes more sense to have the constructor throw when you pass invalid parameters, and to have an `Open()` method that throws when the hardware does not respond.

There are also some less obvious issues with "starting" something from within a constructor, which may not apply to these drivers:

- Interfaces cannot define constructors, so the interface would not completely represent what you're trying to build
- When subclassing a class that "starts" from the constructor, if you want to "start differently", there is no parent constructor to call